# I have 4 colors of cubes: red, yellow, blue and green. How many variants have I got to build a tower of 6 blocks?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 4 colors of cubes: red, yellow, blue and green. How many variants have I got to build a tower of 6 blocks?

My approach:
We have $4$ variants for each block in the tower, so that we get $4^6$ and we need to divide by the amount of permutations that is $6!$, so that we get $4^6/6!$

Am I right?

Comment: I would say a tower has a distinguishable top and bottom, so I think every different ordering represents a different tower, and so I wouldn't divide by anything. Also please check your title: you have **4** colors ..

Comment: Do you also have an infinite number of cubes of a given color?

Comment: $4^6/6!$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The $6!$ part is incorrect. That would be the number of ways to order six distinguishable blocks, which doesn't apply here.

The answer before you took this detour is correct: $4^6$.